# How to auto-run user-interface in Player Pro

Tags: programming, user-interface, cdfplayer

I am about to start constructing a UI that will be run with Player Pro. I have created the following notebook and marked it cells as initialization cells.

```
PlotUi[] := 
  CreateDialog[{Manipulate[
     Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}], {{a, 1}, -2, 2}]}];

PlotUi[]
```

When I select *File | CDF Preview | Player Pro* I get a Player Pro window that shows me the code.  I have to actually execute the code to show the UI.  How can I get the UI to auto-load from the initialization cells and hide (close?) the notebook when it is opened?  Also, how would I close the notebook when the GUI is closed.

The UI will be a processing wizard and the users should not have to execute (or see) any Mathematica code.

Comment: Do you really need to use the old GUIKit, or can you use the newer UI construction methods?

Comment: @Szabolcs I thought that was the way to create more robust GUIs.  I don't have to use it.  I'm using 10.2

Comment: @Szabolcs I removed the GUIKit and put in a `Manipulate`.

Comment: I can't comment on what is more robust, but I think I do know the solution for Dynamic GUIs (untested): instead of *evaluating* `CreateDialog`, which creates a *dialog notebook*, just make the dialog notebook the notebook that the user will open.  The point is that the dialog itself is a notebook.   You can have a `DynamicModule` within which can have an `Initialization :> ...` option for any setup.  But the GUI (at least the part that shows first) doesn't need to be created by evaluating something.  It's just saved in the notebook.

Comment: This of course won't work with GUIKit, but you can have a normal button in the notebook which will launch the GUIKit UI.  I don't know if there are other ways.  I don't have and have never used Player Pro, so this is based on plain Mathematica experience.

Comment: @Szabolcs `Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "dialog.nb"}], PlotUi[]]` does the trick.  Is there a **File | Save As** method of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I save notebooks with multiple GUIs as CDF files and give users CDFPlayer to install.

I have code in the notebook but hide it by collapsing the cells around the GUI that I want the user to see (of course the user can open it and sometimes does by accident).

For your particular problem you could write in your notebook something like:

```
PopupWindow[
 "Plot Sin[a x]",
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}], {{a, 1}, -2, 2}]
 ]
```

and then double click on the string "Plot Sin[a x]" to get the Manipulate in a popup window.

You can make it look more appealing by a myriad of tricks.

For example to make it stand out a bit you could enclose it in frame and use TraditionalForm for the Sin[a x] expression.

```
PopupWindow[
 Framed[Row[{Style["Plot ", 14], 
    Style[TraditionalForm[Sin[a x]], 14]}], Background -> LightCyan],
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}], {{a, 1}, -2, 2}]
 ]
```

Once you collapse it this is all the user sees

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is an interesting idea but I would not want the users to have to launch the interface after opening the _application_. Saving the `CreateDialog` with `Export` is ideal as it loads the UI as needed when the file is open. I do like your idea for a menu of UI wizards but with `NotebookOpen` on the dialogue notebooks  instead of `PopupWindow`.